# How do I heal crippled companions, preferably without wasting supplies or caps?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Veronica got a bit crippled by the boomer artillery, now she's limping around and being all melodramatic, making me promise to bury her in a nice dress.

I'm not playing hardcore mode.

I slept in my bed, but she's still crippled and her HPs did not go back to full either.

I think this is new since the last patch, I distinctly remember companions being healed after sleeping.

How can I heal her again, preferably without wasting supplies or caps?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shoot her in the face, then open the companion wheel and make her use a stimpack.

Works on Hardcore mode as well.

Comment: What?! (15 char)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, on non-hardcore mode you can also just kill the companion and they will be uncrippled and at full health after waking up again.